# Splitting string in java with different delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split the following into a list.

```
 "[A,B], [C,D]";
```

I need to the output as:

```
[A,B]
[C,D]
```

I tried the following, but I get the output as:

```
[A,B
[C,D]
```

Code:

```
ArrayList   result = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(inp.split("\\],")));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well you could use a regex, or you could just split by `", "`: `inp.split(", ")`.

Comment: Just saw which answer you accepted why the complex one ? the 'not followed by not this character' rather than 'followed by bracket' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
inp.split(",\\s*(?![^\\[]*\\])")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/B53gJo/1). It will match a comma and any whitespace after if, after that, there is not any characters different from `[` and then  `]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`,\s*(?=\[)`](https://regex101.com/r/B53gJo/2) which means

- `,` a comma
- `\s*` followed by any amount of space (including 0)
- `(?=\[)` directly followed by an openning square bracket (but

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(inp.split(",\\s*(?=\\[)")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the format of that data, you could use the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches.

Then you could loop the matches and add capture group 1 to a list.

```
\G(\[[A-Z],[A-Z]])(?:,\h*)?
```

In parts:

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[[A-Z],[A-Z]]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:,\h*)?` Optionally match `,` and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ukDN8V/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/yxMEcR)

*Example code*

```
String regex = "\\G(\\[[A-Z],[A-Z]])(?:,\\h*)?";
String string = "[A,B], [C,D]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group(1));
}

for (String element : result)
    System.out.println(element);
```

*Output*

```
[A,B]
[C,D]
```